# Is there a way to increase the width of a particular row after some rows

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 3 columns in which in one column i am using row span based on other columns data. Now i want to increase the width of the row after the row span or the row that separates two dates. My code is as shown below

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="meals-table">

  <thead>

    <tr bgcolor="#328AA4" style="">                      
      <th class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
        <font color="3366CC"> Date
          </th>
      <th class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
        <font color="3366CC"> Food
          </th>

      <th class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
        <font color="3366CC"> Quantity
          </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {% for rdate in entities %} 
  {% for entity in rdate %}  
  {% set counter = 0 %}  
  {% set rowcount = 0 %}
  {% set count = 0 %}
  {% for food in entity %}
  {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% for food in entity %}
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
  {% set rowcount = rowcount + 1 %}
  <tr>       

    {% if rowcount <= 1 %}                
                      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background-color: white;" rowspan="{{counter}}">{{ food.cdate }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 17%;">{{ food.foodname }}</td>               
    <td style="text-align: left; padding-left: 15%;">{{ food.qtyeaten }}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ food.qtyname }}</td>                             
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: Don't use table, use divs for custom table layout.

Comment: "divs for custom table layout" why? a table is what tales are for. tabular data should be represented using table markup, not using div's to act like a table

Comment: Can you post the html output so it can be added to a fiddle rather then the template.

Answer (score 0):

just add width to your style element:

`<th style="width: 40%;  text-align: center ...`

( and it seems that the number of columns in the table-header is not always the same as found in the table-data)